# How do i hide the f:selectItem tag under h:selectOneRadio

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

For `<f:selectItem>` there is no `rendered` attribute. How can I hide a particular `<f:selectItem>` under `<h:selectOneRadio>`?

```html
<h:selectOneRadio id="radio1" styleClass="selectOneRadio" value="#{}" rendered="#{}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="#{ONE}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="PRIVATE" itemLabel="#{TWO}" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="GROUP" itemLabel="#{THREE}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

In above code I want to hide the second item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:selectItem>` is a tag handler (which evaluated during view build time), not a JSF component (which is evaluated during view render time). You can only show/hide it with another tag handler, such as JSTL `<c:if>`.

```html
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="#{ONE}" />
    <c:if test="#{!bean.showPrivate}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="PRIVATE" itemLabel="#{TWO}" />
    </c:if>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="GROUP" itemLabel="#{THREE}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Only when `#{bean}` is been prepared during view render time by an iterating JSF component such as `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` then the above won't work and you really have to do it in the backing bean code instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `f:selectItems` .
For example:

```
 <h:selectOneRadio id="radio1" styleClass="selectOneRadio" rendered="true" value="controller.value">
    <f:selectItems  value="#{controller.items}"  />
 </h:selectOneRadio >
```

This is class controller:

```
 public clss Controller(){

        private List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        public Collection<SelectItem> getItems(){
        if (items.isEmpty()){
          createItems();
         }
         return this.items;
        }

        public private createItems(){
          if (condition){ //Here you can hidden the selectItem
             this.items.add(new SelectItem(value,label));
          }
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to surround it  in

```
 <h:panelGrid  rendered="">
   h:selectOneRadio
 </h:panelGrid  >
```

EDITED:

or use

```
<h:panelGroup>
```

Edit

its not good idea but i think you can do it by code redundancy as follow

```
       <h:panelGroup rendered="#{}">
            <h:selectOneRadio id="radio1" styleClass="selectOneRadio" rendered="true">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="one" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="PRIVATE" itemLabel="two" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="GROUP" itemLabel="THREE"  /> 
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:panelGroup>
         <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!}">
            <h:selectOneRadio id="radio11" styleClass="selectOneRadio" rendered="true">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="one" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="PRIVATE" itemLabel="two" />

            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: yes i already think about it, but i have multiple select items then every time i need to use radio button for every selectitem.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the markup/source, but guessing from the heading, I will suggest

`$("a.selectOneRadio f.selectItem").hide()`

should do the job assuming

```
1) selectOneRadio is the class name of the a tag.
2) selectItem is the class name of the f tag.
3) f is not a tag in HTML. So if `f` is also a class name, you would have to use `.f .selectItem`
```

If you can please provide some details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `disabled` property on `f:selectItem` elements, if that fulfills your needs. Otherwise you will have to add them manually as Michel Foucault suggested.